# Twitter media cannot be played from Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, 16.10, codecs, twitter

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 but it cannot play some videos from Twitter in Firefox. Instead, I get a message, something like

> This media cannot be reproduced.

If I open the Firefox console, I see this message:

> The video on this page can’t be played. Your system may not have the required video codecs for: video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E mp4a.40.2"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution is straightforward: just install ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: Nope, I've got that installed already.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and Firefox 57. And I still have the "Play DRM content" turned off to boot.

Comment: not all content is drm'd, but all content requires a player.

Comment: Worked for me with Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 4):

I did have all required codecs, tools & libs installed (ffmpeg, restricted extras, etc), but still was getting a lot of (but not all) media not playing -- mostly noticeable on twitter. Some played, others did not.

I was able to resolve this by going into Firefox `preferences > content > DRM content`; the check box ["Play DRM Content"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm) was *not* checked. After checking the box and restarting firefox, these media once again started playing in firefox. (Sample [test tweet](https://twitter.com/BraddJaffy/status/875359689684529153) to verify.)

Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty), Firefox 54.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Note also be sure that there's not ad blocking or other blocking (/etc/hosts) preventing the content from being displayed, e.g, blocking anything from twitter.com (etc); or if the actual image is from another site, and that site is blocked (e.g., see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1076592  ).  Some trial and error may be required if you want to keep most blocks in place.

Comment: That might be my problem.  I'll stick with no DRM content though on principle.  Oh well.

Comment: Enabling "Play DRM Content" doesn't fix the problem for me... only after installing ffmpeg as suggested in @brandizzi's answer and restarting FF it started playing videos (without enabling DRM).

Comment: indeed --  playing content is dependent on having a player -- drm or no.